# QTableView scroll to new added row

Tags: c++, qt, row, qtableview, model-view

To add new rows to model I am calling `beginInsertRows` and `endInsertRows()`. How to configure the view to scroll to new added rows and select it. I can do it by sending some signals but maybe Qt has standard way for it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Create a slot in your form class and connect it to the model's `rowsInserted` signal. The slot should contain the following:

```
void My_form::model_rows_inserted(const QModelIndex & parent, int start, int end) {
  view->scrollTo(model->index(start, 0));
}
```

Note that you cannot (and should not) do this from your model. The model should know nothing about the view.

Answer (score 8):

`view->scrollToBottom();` is better solution, because if using scrollTo metthod, new row in some cases is not full visible

Comment: This wouldn't work if there was some sorting being done on the QTableView.